# Associations in restangular models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I need to define associations in restangular models. I'd like to define them to use it like `user.post.title`, but I'm running into some problems with that.

For the models I have my own service layer, it would look like this:

```
app.factory('models.user', function(Restangular) {
  var users;
  users = {};
  return {get: function(user_id) {
    return users[user_id] || (users[user_id] = Restangular.one('users', user_id).get());
  }};
});

app.factory('models.post', ['Restangular', 'models.user', function(Restangular, User) {
  Restangular.extendModel('posts', function(post) {
    post.user || (post.user = User.get(post.user_id));
    return post;
  });
  return {get: function(post_id) {
    return Restangular.one('posts', post_id).get();
  }};
}]);
```

With this I can do `post.user().first_name` to navigate from a post to its user, but the code is quite ugly and doesn't really work well in some situations, like updating the models it runs into an infinite loop trying to clone the post object.

Any idea how to define associations in restangular models?

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: Since Angular 1.2 I moved this to get `post.user` as a resolved promise instead of a promise, then i'll be undefined for a while until the promise is resolved, then the post will get the user. Other than that, not much...